# Creating orders from Partner Community

Tags: partner-communities, order

I have a situation here. I have an internal user who creates the partner account. So by default the account owner is the internal user. I want the partner users to be able to access only the one partner account so I have set external sharing in OWD as Private for account.

Now my requirement is that the partner user should be able to create orders. I have enabled orders tab in the community and then given CRED access to orders in profile. Still I am unable to create the order and getting an error message "You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary"

This is because internally sales force maintains a master-detail relationship between Account and Orders and since account access is private , its failing.

How do i get past this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from another user.

Problem followed by resolution
3
down vote
accepted
Activating orders is normally done by the organization shipping or provisioning the product ordered. In PRM the Partner normally sells the product and/or delivers additional services but does not ship/provision/deliver the order. So that's why only users with the Salesforce license (thus internal users) can activate an order.

There probably is a way around this:

Add custom field boolean 'Activate' to Order.

Add the custom field to the page the Partner Community User sees so the user can check it.

Write an batch apex job with:

a start method getting all order objects with an Activate flag set to true
an execute method truly activating the order via setting the status field and probably the activatedby and activated field. I couldn't find any documentation on this so you probably have to play around with it a little bit.
Schedule the apex batch. Look at write and schedule batch jobs for additional help on that.
Hope this helps!